# jquery - find first previous node with certain properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

regardless of parent/child-relations etc, how do I find the node closest above $(this) node with a certain property, for example class="field"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not exactly what I meant by closest, I ended up doing it like this:

```
$(this).parent('.jdpicker_w').next('.spacer').children()
```

Comment: Your own "answer" doesn't even seem to be related to your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).closest(".field");
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (assuming .field is a parent of this):

```
$(this).closest(".field");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parents(".field:first")
```